# The "Copy" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I'm using windows 10.

After updated VS 2017 to 15.8.1 i started getting error below:

```
The "Copy" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CopyFile(String src, String dst, Boolean failIfExists)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFileWithLogging(FileState sourceFileState, FileState destinationFileState)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.DoCopyWithRetries(FileState sourceFileState, FileState destinationFileState, CopyFileWithState copyFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.DoCopyIfNecessary(FileState sourceFileState, FileState destinationFileState, CopyFileWithState copyFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<<CopyParallel>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyParallel(CopyFileWithState copyFile, Int32 parallelism, List`1& destinationFilesSuccessfullyCopied)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.Execute(CopyFileWithState copyFile, Int32 parallelism)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I've tryed to move project to another physical drive, but it wasn't helpful.

The projects may vary and error is not repeating every build.
What may cause this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313413/visual-studio-the-copy-task-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: Can you please share your code to copy?

Comment: Seeing CopyFile() throw an SEH exception is very, very bad.  You  cannot trust this machine anymore, use another one.  Some odds that getting rid of the installed anti-malware product can rescue it, ymmv.

Comment: @RobertHarvey my project was in local drive and i changed drives twice

Comment: @HansPassant you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was **InfoWatch**,  corporate info safety system, anti-malware like product.